# MVVM View-First Approach How Change View

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view

Does anybody have an idea how to change screens (views) in a MVVM View-First-Approach (The view instantiates the ViewModel:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMLocator},
Path=Find[EntranceViewModel]}"
```

)

For example:
In my MainWindow (Shell) I show a entrance view with a Button "GoToBeach".

```
<Window>
  <DockPanel>
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding Title}" />
    <view.EntranceView DockPanel.Dock="Top" />    
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

When the button is clicked I want to get rid of the "EntranceView" and show the "BeachView".
I am really curious if somebody knows a way to keep the View-First Approach and change the screen (view) to the "BeachView".
I know there are several ways to implement it in a ViewModel-First Approach, but that is not the question. 
Perhabs I missed something in my mvvm investigation and  can't see the wood for the trees... otherwise i am
hoping for a inspiring discussion.

Comment: What if the DockPanel has both EntranceView and BeachView, with each having their visibility property bound to properties of the VM ? I am not sure I understand the implications of this ViewFirst approach.

Comment: I am also not sure if I get it right :) With two views its ok, but if you have a larger application with 20 or more views... It's not really nice code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to have all views in the (MainWindow(Shell) and using Triggers for their visibility. But having a lot of different screens (views) all declared in the MainWindow doesnt feel right for me...

This question came up while reading this nice way of using MEF with MVVM I found on John Papas Blog: Simple ViewModel Locator for MVVM: The Patients Have Left the Asylum . But as nice as this marriage of view and viewmodel is, it seems like there is no way to change screens that satisfies me. :)

So in my opinion if you have a lot of screens(views) you better use a ViewModel-First-Approach...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might help:
[Creating a ViewModel : do it before or after model data is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688994/creating-a-viewmodel-do-it-before-or-after-model-data-is-available/2690607#2690607)

Failing that, how about creating the ViewModel once only at startup, and assigning it to each View window as it's created (rather than creating a new ViewModel each time). Then just close the first View and open up a new View as required, reassigning the single ViewModel instance.

Comment: VMLocator could have singleton instances of the ViewModels. Thats not the point. This question is just about a clean View-First-Approach, where every view creates its ViewModel or gets an instance of its view and not the opposite. When you assign a viewmodel to the content and handle the view via datatemplate, its a viewmodel-first apporach.

Comment: @CodeWeasel you sure? I think thats a View first approach.

Comment: @Lisa: Can you please give me a further explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Prism (i.e. the composite application library). Prism facilitates navigation between views via the region manager. This might be overkill for your application and can take a while to get your head around. Prism also allows you to develop using the MVVM pattern as well.

You can find more information about prism and prism navigation in the Prism [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx).